# How To add all the element in textboxes into an array?

Tags: c#, winforms

Actually I'm facing problems with my textboxes and just to say that its my first Visual C# Application i do.

I just have many textboxes, around 14 textboxes and all i want is that after the user enter the values in each on i need this value to be saved in an array Temp[]

for example (

```
  textbox1.text=1  so Temp[0]=1

 textbox2.text=4  so Temp[1]=4
```

and etc....

I've included also a pic for my app:

[image]

so as you can see i the user must enter values for the first set and another values for the second set and i need to save the entered values in each set in an array to show later the union and the intersection of the sets.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why now add the data first and at the end do a foreach loop that will will loop over the controls that are of TextBox, and add that text data into an Array[] or List<> or Hashtable, there are so many options here..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
For 1st panel
    int a=0;

```
foreach (TextBox tbx in Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    Temp1[a]= tbx.text ;
    a++;
}
```

For 2nd Panel
    a=0;

```
foreach (TextBox tbx in Panel2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    Temp2[a]= tbx.text ;
    a++;
}
```

**Edit**: You have to define 1st set of textboxes in panel1 and 2nd set in panel2.

Comment: That's what I would have done as well as what I have suggested.. +1 to your code..

Comment: I just thought about your code.. look at how his screen shot is.. would it be better to create a Dictionary<string,string> he would need to store the textbox name as well as the Textbox.Text .. what are your thoughts.. the tab order would seem to be very important I would think

Comment: Thanks for your reply i'll try this. im a beginner in visual c#

Comment: user1924180, how are you keeping track of which TextBox the data is coming from..?

Comment: Thanks DJ KRAZE. Dont think Dictionary<string,string> is what required  because user1924180 said he want to store all number in array. If i am not wrong

Comment: hi syed mohsin yes that what i want just to store all numbers from textboxes in an array

Comment: ill try this  just give me a moment im just happy :) after hours of thinking

Comment: guys there is an error in my code it say: cannot convert implicitly from string to int ??

Comment: probably i must initialize a string array ?

Comment: yes initialize string array or try Temp2[a]= Convert.toInt32(tbx.text) ;